# Length of exceptional sequences

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field $k$. A module $M$ is called exceptional in case $End_A(M)=k$ and $Ext_A^i(M,M)=0$ for $i>0$.
A tuple $(M,N)$ is called exceptional in case $M$ and $N$ are exceptional and $Ext_A^l(N,M)=0$ for all $l \geq 0$.
A sequence $(M_1,M_2,...,M_t)$ is called exceptional if all tuples $(M_i,M_{i+1})$ are exceptional.
Exceptional sequences have been studied for hereditary algebras (see for example http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_2011__61_3_1061_0/) but I have found no systematic study for general algebras.

> Question: Is it true that the length of a exceptional sequence is at most $n$ when $n$ is the number of simples of the algebra (at least when the algebra has finite global dimension or is representation-finite)?

Comment: I would say that the systematic study of exceptional collections for finite dimensional algebras is called the theory of quasi-hereditary algebras.